# Выбрать данные по дате с помощью Entity Framework Core 6.0.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Как выбрать данные за выбранный период времени с помощь EF Core 6.0.1. Я пробовал следующим образом :

```
public ICollection<Order> SelectUsersOrders(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return _db.Orders.Where(i => i.UserId == id).ToList().Where(i => i.NowDateTime.Date == start).ToList().Where(i=> i.NowDateTime.Date == end).ToList();
    }
```

Так же пробовал и так:

```
public ICollection<Order> SelectUsersOrders(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            return _db.Orders.Where(i => i.UserId == id).ToList().Where(i => i.NowDateTime.Date == start && i.NowDateTime.Date == end).ToList();
        }
```

И такой вариант я так же использовал в поимках решения своей проблемы:

```
public ICollection<Order> SelectUsersOrders(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            return _db.Orders.Where(i => i.UserId == id && i.NowDateTime.Date == start && i=> i.NowDateTime.Date == end).ToList();
        }
```

вызов и передача параметров осуществляется следующим образом:

```
    var dateStart = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    var dateEnd = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
    var userId = 2;
 using (var db = new AppContext())
  {
    var orderRepository = new OrderRepository(db);
                
    var selectOrder = orderRepository.SelectUsersOrders(userId, dateStart, dateEnd);
}
```

Данные в БД есть, но на выходе при передаче всех параметров данные не выгружиются, помогите пожалуйста разобраться и правильно получить нужные мне данные определённого пользователя за определённый период времени[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За первые два варианты нужно отлучать от клавиатуры.

Comment: `Where(i => i.UserId == id && i.NowDateTime.Date >= start && i.NowDateTime.Date <= end)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Первые 2 варианта безысходность ))) Тут на этапе изучения главное не отлучать, а вовремя бить по рукам и говорить как правильно )))  Спасибо за ответ и помощь